# TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY not working on Android 10

Tags: java, android

In my application I pull up the Android settings menu using:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
i.putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
i.putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_NO_HEADERS, true);
startActivity(i);
```

In this settings menu, pressing the < button on the left top directs me to a higher level of the Android settings menu instead of returning to my app. I need to block this < button so users only use the back or home navigation keys to return to my app.

With Android 9 (and below) I used the following solution: I added an TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY over the < button section block the button from being activated which worked great. Now however in Android 10 my overlay is not on top anymore and I cannot catch the touch/click.

Does anyone have suggestions or solutions on this? Thanks!

Comment: Nobody here to have a solution for this? I do not understand why it is working on Android 9 and not on 10.